# Python PySide2 (Internal c++ Object Already Deleted)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

Got a snag with PySide2 here. So, I'm creating widgets using PySide2 through Qt Designer, and then I'm reassigning variables from the UI files, something like this:

```
self.refresh_btn = self.ui.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'refresh_btn')
```

But when I try to use self.refresh_btn in another func,

The system log throws this at me:

```
#RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (PySide2.QtWidgets.QPushButton) already deleted.
```

Any clues on how to tackle this one? Appreciate any help!

```
import os
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader

_CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

class TEST(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    WIN_NAME = 'xxxx'

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self._init_ui()    

    def _init_ui(self):
        ui_file = QFile(_CURRENT_DIR + "/TEST.ui")
        ui_file.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
        loader = QUiLoader()
        self.ui = loader.load(ui_file)
        ui_file.close()
        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.ui)
 
        self.setObjectName(self.WIN_NAME)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.WIN_NAME)

        self.get_widgets_from_ui()
        self.create_connections()
        self.show()



    def get_widgets_from_ui(self):
        self.refresh_btn=self.ui.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'refresh_btn')
        self.clear_all_btn=self.ui.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'clear_all_btn')
        print(self.clear_all_btn)
      
    def create_connections(self):
        self.refresh_btn.clicked.connect(self.add_list_widget_to_sqe)
    
    #i need use this fuc to dynamic add wiget to the main widget
    def add_list_widget_to_sqe(self):
        # print(self.layout)
        print(self.clear_all_btn)# just test the clear_all_btn is living
        pass

test=TEST()
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. It all works perfectly fine for me using PySide-5.15.12 on Linux. Even so, it seems rather pointless reassigning variables in this way, since they're already available as `self.ui.refresh_btn` and `self.ui.clear_all_btn`.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't cause the error you are mentioning, but another one "QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget", which is expected, since you are not creating a QApplication. This leads me to think that you're leaving out other important aspects of the code that actually cause the issue, so please provide a valid [mre].

Comment: Indeed, I made a mistake.
self.ui.clear_all_btn, it works！！